# How to add DOCTYPE to the second line of an already existing element tree?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I have code that creates XML, but I need the DOCTYPE header on the second line of the file. I saw that everyone uses lxml for this but I am already using `xml.etree.ElementTree`. Can I use both in the same file on the same tree. This is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET  
from lxml import etree


global num_of_parallel_tests

num_of_parallel_tests = 5
  
  
def GenerateXML(fileName) : 
      
    root = ET.Element("suite") 
    root.set("thread-count", str(num_of_parallel_tests))
    root.set("name", "Selenium Automated Test w/ TestNG")
    root.set("parallel", "tests")

    for x in range(1, num_of_parallel_tests + 1):
        test = ET.Element("test")
        test.set("name", "Testing Row " + str(x))
        parameter = ET.SubElement(test, "parameter")
        parameter.set("name", "Row")
        parameter.set("value", str(x))
        classes = ET.SubElement(test, "classes")
        a_class = ET.SubElement(classes, "class")
        a_class.set("name", "RealPackage.ParallelTests")


        root.append(test)
      

      
    tree = ET.ElementTree(root) 

    


      
    with open (fileName, "wb") as files : 
        tree.write(files) 
  
# Driver Code 
if __name__ == "__main__":  
    GenerateXML("GeneratedXML.xml")
```

And it produces this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<suite parallel="tests" name="Selenium Automated Test w/ TestNG" thread-count="5">


-<test name="Testing Row 1">

<parameter name="Row" value="1"/>


-<classes>

<class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>

</classes>

</test>


-<test name="Testing Row 2">

<parameter name="Row" value="2"/>


-<classes>

<class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>

</classes>

</test>


-<test name="Testing Row 3">

<parameter name="Row" value="3"/>


-<classes>

<class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>

</classes>

</test>


-<test name="Testing Row 4">

<parameter name="Row" value="4"/>


-<classes>

<class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>

</classes>

</test>


-<test name="Testing Row 5">

<parameter name="Row" value="5"/>


-<classes>

<class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>

</classes>

</test>

</suite>
```

But I need this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="5" name="BlogSuite" parallel="tests">
<test name="Test 1">
<parameter name="Row" value="1"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
  <test name="Test 2">
<parameter name="Row" value="2"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
    <test name="Test 3">
<parameter name="Row" value="3"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
    <test name="Test 4">
<parameter name="Row" value="4"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
      <test name="Test 5">
<parameter name="Row" value="5"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RealPackage.ParallelTests"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
  </suite>
```

Notice the first two lines are different.

Comment: You want to add an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was this line:
`tree.write(files, encoding="utf-8", xml_declaration=True, doctype='<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">')`